# how can i group excerpts by fields in solr/lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

When I index the following document in Solr:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "978-0641723445",
    "name" : "The Lightning Thief",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Rick Jackson and the Olympians",
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1423103349",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "The Sea of Monsters",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Rick Jackson and the Olympians",
  }
]
```

and run the following query:
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?hl.fl=name&hl=on&indent=on&q=rick&rows=20&wt=json

I'd like to have an excerpt that consists of each matched field's name and a sub-excerpt of the field's contents (the actual format of the sub-excerpt is not so important):

```
"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": { ...
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 2,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
                "id": "978-0641723445",
                .. {
                    "id": "978-1423103349",
                    ..
                }],
            "highlighting": {
                "978-0641723445": {
                    "author": "Rick Riordan",
                    "series_t": "Rick Riordan and..."
                },
                "978-1423103349": {
                    "author": "Rick Riordan",
                    "series_t": "Rick Riordan and..."

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I have to change my solr query to accomplish this? Or does this change require a custom solr/lucene highlighter?

Comment: Have you tried `hl.requireFieldMatch=true` together with `hl.fl=*` - this should give you highlighting on all fields where the query matched.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, this solution works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with @MatsLindh's solution (see comment).